# How to add class for Reference Block Arguments in xml file?

Tags: blocks, magento2.3.4, header, class, reference

I have created custom in link header,

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\view\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Custom Link </argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> customlink </argument>             

        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Move the element using

```
<move element="custom-link" destination="header.panel" after="logo" />
```

I can't able to add desgn for this link. I need to add images for this custom link and do some customization. How to achieve my task?

Comment: Can't you do it by making custom block class and template for header.links?

Comment: can you pls guide me for this? Above is my custom link script?

Comment: Actually, I haven't done much work on this, just added a link. But I think for customization you can start from there. I'm writing a bit of code in answer for default.xml, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

See if below code helps.

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\LinkArticle" name="header.links" template="Vendoe_Module::link.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header_links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: What is link.phtml? should i add css here?

Comment: Yes you can add styling/css here.

Comment: Where should i place link.html?

Comment: view/frontend/templates/

Comment: okay. let me do it.

Comment: Yes, I think you'll have to find the right referenceContailer for header links as for footer I used `footer_links` and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117329/discussion-between-zus-and-abdul-samad-abbasi).

Comment: can you pls join https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117329/discussion-between-zus-and-abdul-samad-abbasi